# Sacrificing database standards for a faster application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, performance, normalization

In this case, database standards in terms of eliminating data redundancy. Firstly, I'm not sure how to define data redundancy in this case. It's normally defined as same data appearing in multiple tables. But isn't any data that can be reached without having to explicitly save it into a database redundant? Take the following example:

There's a database for soccer betting. There are 2 tables:

- betting_tickets
- bets

The "betting_tickets" table is used for saving the whole betting ticket. The "bets" table is used for saving each individual bet on a match and so every individual bet (row) in this table references a specific betting ticket from which it came from, in the "betting_tickets" table. Here's how the "bets" table would look in a shortened version:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| bet_id | ticket_id* |  home_club  |  away_club  | bet_outcome |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   |      1     |   Chelsea   |   Arsenal   |     Hit     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    2   |      1     |  Tottenham  |    Stoke    |     Hit     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    3   |      2     |    Fulham   |   Everton   |     Miss    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    4   |      2     |  Liverpool  |   West Ham  |     Hit     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    5   |      2     |  Sunderland |  Hull City  |     Hit     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the "betting_tickets" table in a shortened version:

```
------------------------------
| ticket_id | ticket_outcome |
------------------------------
|     1     |      Hit       |
------------------------------
|     2     |      Miss      |
------------------------------
```

Now lets say the "bets" table has more than a million records in it and the "betting_tickets" about a 5th of that. If I wanted to find out how many betting tickets were missed because of only 1 missed bet I'd have to loop through more than a million records, counting and checking whether they're ones where only 1 game spoiled the betting ticket. Something which would be slow even in C#. But if I were to make a column in the "betting_tickets" table that states how many bets were missed or something similar, wouldn't this vastly improve the speed of the task I'm trying to perform?

Also, would this column be considered redundant? Even though the data doesn't appear in multiple tables, it's still data that can be reached without it having to occupy its own column in the database.

As stated in the tags, this is a situation of SQL Server and C#.

Comment: If the question is "can you use denormalized / redundant information to improve performance", then the obvious answer is *sure*. The trickier question is "*when* should you?" (which depends on a **lot** of context and measured, actual performance data), with a follow up of "how do we make sure the redundant information is correct?". For example: every question on stackoverflow stores (in the row data) the number of answers, the net score, and the accepted answer identifier. That data is entirely redundant (the "master" for this is via related tables), but *by heck* does it save a lot of reads!

Comment: Do you actually have a performance issue to fix or are you just optimizing prematurely? If it's the former, fine, go ahead and denormalize. If it's the latter, please stop right now.

Comment: You could probably defined an indexed view that provides this information very quickly without the usual denormalization problems.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with acfrancis, step away from the tables.